# Grep file for one target (+ next 3 lines) OR another target (just that line)

Tags: command-line, grep, search

I want to search a file for two target strings. For the first target I wish to return that line and the 3 lines following it. For the second target string I want to return just the line containing the target.

So I want to do something like this pseudo command:

```
cat <file> | grep (-A 3 'target1') OR ('target2')
```

The problem is I don't know how to prevent the `-A 3` from being applied to the second target.

Is there a way to achieve this? I can't run the two `grep`s separately because the lines are ordered.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, in sed:

```
sed -n -e '/target1/,+3p' -e '/target2/p'
```

or in awk:

```
awk '$0 ~ "target1" {a = FNR+3} (FNR <= a) || ($0 ~ "target2")'
```

If you use GNU awk (aka `gawk`) then the `~` operator should accept the same regular expression patterns as GNU `grep -E`.

Answer (score 0):

Just grep twice. If you need the lines interleaved, then use line numbers and sort

```bash
(cat <file> | grep -A 3 'target1') && (cat <file> | grep 'target2')
# or for interleaved line numbers
# sed is required because grep prefixes lines that are included with -A with <line#>- instead of <line#>:
((cat <file> | grep -n -A 3 'target1') && (cat <file> | -n 'target2')) | sort -n | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\)-/\1:/g' | uniq
# or if you don't want the line numbers in your output
((cat <file> | grep -n -A 3 'target1') && (cat <file> | -n 'target2')) | sort -n | sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\)-/\1:/g' | uniq | sed 's/^[0-9]\+://g'
```

Comment: On the bottom line did you mean to omit the second grep and put it before sort? `(cat <file> | -n 'target2')) | grep sort`

Comment: @user997112 fixed it.